# How to preserve colors in logs with Multitail?

Tags: colors, tail, ansi-escape

Output of `tail logs/development.log` in XFCE Terminal:

[image: output of tail logs/development.log in XFCE Terminal]

```
multitail log/development.log
```

[image: output of multitail log/development.log]

Rails adds escape codes to log files automatically. See `development.log` file:

```
  ^[[1m^[[36m (84.1ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mCREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar(255) NOT NULL) ^[[0m
  ^[[1m^[[35m (92.6ms)^[[0m  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations" ("version")
  ^[[1m^[[36m (0.2ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT version FROM "schema_migrations"^[[0m
  ^[[1m^[[35m (159.3ms)^[[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20130327221553')
  ^[[1m^[[36m (59.9ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20130326152730')^[[0m
  ^[[1m^[[35m (59.8ms)^[[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20130327173637')
```

`multitail -c` produce non-usable output.

[image: Output of multitail -c]

How to colorize logs in Multitail without writing own color scheme?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's all about interpreting [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) which does terminal not `tail` itself and have to do `multitail` as well.
 It can be done with `-cT ANSI` option:

```
-cT term    interpret terminal-codes from file/command (for terminal type 'term')
```

Example:

```
$ multitail -cT ansi log/development.log
multiple files:
$ multitail -cT ansi log/development.log -cT ANSI log/test.log
```

[image: colorized output of multitail -cT ansi log/development.log]

Comment: I can't seem to make this work with a piped input... is there a different command for that? edit:: got this working, you just have to make sure the order is correct. multitail -j -cT ansi doesn't work, but multitail -cT ansi -j does

Comment: This does not seem to work together with `-Q i path`. I am using version 6.5.0 of `multitail`. Even without `-Q` it fails to render certain colors like light black (90). My only working solution was to go back to using `tail` which renders everything perfectly. I had to go back to writing a single log file, and using `logrotate` to rotate it.